# Conflict with WP and .htaccess mod_rewrite?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been struggling for days trying to find a way to allow certain redirects in my WP site without them showing on the address bar.

It should work like this: if the user types `mydomain.com/abc` he is redirected to `mydomain.com/xyz` but in his browser the address bar still displays `mydomain.com/abc`

Now that sounds simple enough but I can't make it work for the life of me. I thought the canonical_redirect function in WP was causing some kind of conflict, so I disabled it, but it still won't work.

I've tried this code in .htaccess (and several variants)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^en-uk(/.*)?$ /en$1 [L]
```

The redirect works fine, but the URL in the address bar changes to the new page, which is **not** what I want.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /xyz/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /xyz/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: No luck. Thanks though.